# Display only the features of a layer that are intersected by a dynamic atlas layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, filter, overlay, atlas, intersect

Is there a way for a layer (line) that has the symbology displayed dynamically by Atlas to determine ("filter") the symbology display of another layer (polygon) by intersection?

Example of what I need:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Presumably each of the line groups has a distinctive attribute value.  If you do a spatial join of the polygons to the lines, then create a field in the polygons to match the line values you could use that in your Atlas.  If you have multiple line groups in the same polygons that complicates things.  You then need to duplicate those polys so one set could have one line group values and another the next line group value in the field you are using.